# Qual API utilizar para aplicações Java Desktop

Tags: java, aplicação-desktop

Estou querendo desenvolver um projeto Java Desktop e gostaria de analisar qual seria a melhor API para isso. Estou precisando de algo como o estado da arte das APIs desktop para Java. Eu fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei maiores referências ao Electron, que é uma API que permite usar um container embutido na aplicação para que a mesma não seja exposta num navegador. Não sei se é a única opção (só encontrei essa atual, JavaFX e SWT parecem estar defasadas), então as minhas perguntas são:

1. Quais APIs para Java são recomendadas atualmente para aplicações Desktop?
2. Prós e contras dessas APIs

Comment: Tudo desktop em geral eu acredito que esteja defasados hoje em dia. Java pior ainda, por não ter apis q preste pra desktop. Até pq o futuro é nuvem, então não investir em desktop seria retrocesso mesmo.

Comment: https://josephg.com/blog/electron-is-flash-for-the-desktop/

Comment: @Articuno, mas temos por exemplo IDEs que são Desktop. Acho que ainda teremos isso por um tempo, por isso acho importante pensar em formas atuais de desenvolver para Desktop.

Comment: Acho curioso você falar de API Java Desktop e citar JavaFX, SWT e Electron, mas não falar do Swing que é a biblioteca padrão para isso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, Swing não é mais suportado desde o Java 8. O que veio para substituí-lo foi o JavaFX.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra De onde foi que você tirou isso? Swing é suportado sim no Java 10 e também no 11 early access. Pelo contrário, a API que a Oracle está querendo jogar fora no Java 11 ou 12 é o JavaFX. Inclusive, outro dia vi um método no Swing que foi acrescentado no Java 9 ou 10, vou procurar e te passar o link. Aliás, observe que nem o módulo `java.desktop` e nem o pacote `javax.swing` têm um `@Deprecated`.

Comment: O que não é mais suportado são as applets desde o Java 9. Mas applet é uma coisa e swing é outra.

Comment: [Annotation `@javax.swing.SwingContainer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingContainer.html) - since Java 9. [Package `java.awt.desktop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/desktop/package-summary.html) - since Java 9. [Link relevante](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-F3F094FE-6542-441B-AA5D-766AE21D0A59).

Comment: Swing parou de ser atualizado desde o java 8, mas nunca entrou em status `deprecated` ou removido. Quem quiser usar, api ta ai disponivel, so nao se pode esperar melhorias por parte da mantenetora do java, pq isso nao irá ocorrer mais.

Comment: @Articuno e Giuliana Bezerra - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4842658 - Observe que [aqui, (Java 11 EA)](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) você acha dois métodos `addAll`. Mas [aqui (Java 10)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) você não os acha.

Comment: @VictorStafusa isso eu concordo que ela tenha que corrigir mesmo, bugs, por mais antiga que seja a api, é inadmissivel serem mantidos, mas eu quis dizer melhorias do tipo, a api swing peca um pouco em performance e complexidade, se eles tivessem com objetivo de melhorar a api, acho que tem muita coisa a ser melhorada por ai, o multithreading de swing ja é algo a se estudar pq, particulamente, eu acho muito ruim manipular coisas usando aquele swingworker. Isso em situacoes que ele é viavel, claro.

Comment: @Articuno Isso que eu linkei acima não é exatamente correção de bug, e sim melhoria, embora isso seja debatível. Você pode muito bem botar um `for` (ou até mesmo usar um stream) para chamar o `add` no seu `DefaultListModel`, adicionando os itens um por um, ou então usar a sua própria implementação de `ListModel` para fazer algo mais complexo. O que essa pequena mudança dá, são métodos `addAll` para ser mais conveniente de usar e também ter um melhor desempenho ao diminuir o overhead gerado ao acrescentar os elementos um a um.

Comment: @Articuno No entanto, é verdade que a Oracle disponibiliza poucos recursos (financeiros ou humanos) para o desenvolvimento de Java no desktop e tem pouco interesse em disponibilizar mais, e esse é o principal motivo pelo qual as coisas lá andam bastante lentamente.

Comment: @Articuno o fato de ter parado de ser atualizado pra mim é desuso da API. Acredito que só usam no mercado porque ainda não migraram pra coisas mais novas.

Comment: Já que virou fórum, Como está a situação de GUI do Java? Se quiserem pode responder no chat...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A verdade é que nenhuma API para Java no desktop ganhou muito impulso. Java no desktop sempre ficou atrás dos concorrentes, ficando sempre restrito a um nicho.

Não há muitas APIs para Java no desktop por aí, mas existem algumas:

- Electron - Uma API muito rica, mas não tem nada a ver com Java, e sim JavaScript. Ele usa uma implementação embutida do Chrome por debaixo dos panos. A vantagem é que para trabalhar com ela, você usa as mesmas tecnologias para desenvolver na web: HTML, Javascript, CSS, Ajax, etc. A desvantagem é que ele vai subir um navegador inteiro por debaixo dos panos, o que tende a consumir muito mais memória, processamento, bateria e espaço em disco do que a maioria das demais soluções, vez que o Chrome não é exatamente conhecido por tentar economizar esses recursos.
- AWT - É a primeira API desktop que surgiu para o Java, existindo desde o Java 1.0 há mais de 20 anos, então é suportada em todo lugar que tem Java para desktop. Ela tem alguns componentes antigos, porém grande parte deles (mas nem todos) são obsoletos. Alguns dos que não são obsoletos são utilizados como base para o Swing e para o JavaFX, enquanto que outros servem como válvula de escape para coisas que o Swing e o JavaFX não fazem. Há duas partes importantes aqui: Componentes *heavyweight* como `java.awt.Button` são obsoletos (embora não tenham uma anotação `@Deprecated` neles), enquanto que componentes base como `java.awt.Window` continuam em uso até hoje.  Os componentes dela são implementados por meio de ligações a componentes nativos (disponibilizados por meio do sistema operacional). Ninguém recomenda usar os componentes AWT diretamente. Na minha opinião, a API dele é horrível e difícil de se utilizar.
- Swing - É a API padrão para o desenvolvimento de aplicações desktop em Java. Ela é dita como sendo a substituta do AWT, mas isso é apenas uma meia-verdade. Na verdade, o Swing executa por cima do AWT. Enquanto que no AWT, os componentes são implementados nativamente pelo sistema operacional, o Swing usa a abordagem de implementar os componentes totalmente em Java, o que os torna bastante flexíveis. Entretanto, considero que o Swing tem uma API pesada, confusa, difícil de se utilizar corretamente, difícil de ser aprendida e extremamente verbosa, e que esse foi o principal motivo que levou o Java a nunca conseguir se popularizar no deskop. Outro problema é que a Oracle tem pouco interesse em investir no desenvolvimento desktop, e por essa razão, não espere muitas novidades com o Swing.
- JavaFX - Outra API adicionada com a intenção de substituir a anterior (no caso o Swing), mas que na verdade faz uso da anterior. O JavaFX executa por cima do Swing, então essa ideia de substituição é outra uma meia-verdade. Não tenho muita experiência com ela não, mas mas no pouco que usei, tende a ser mais fácil que fazer o equivalente em Swing, e também tenta se aproximar um pouco dos padrões comuns do desenvolvimento web. Entretanto, ela tem a desvantagem de não disponibilizar todos os recursos que o Swing te dá. Outra coisa a se notar é que [a Oracle quer se livrar dela para que ela siga sendo desenvolvida de forma independente](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3261066/java/javafx-will-be-removed-from-the-java-jdk.html).
- SWT - Uma API em Java criada pela fundação Eclipse que não é feita em cima do AWT. Ela adota uma abordagem oposta a do Swing, e busca desenvolver o máximo de funcionalidades possíveis nativamente para ter o melhor desempenho possível, e por esse motivo é bem menos flexível que o Swing ou que o JavaFX. Não tenho experiência com ela, mas a única vez que fui tentar mexer, acabei desistindo. Tem pouco desenvolvimento ativo.
- [Liquid Engine](https://github.com/LiquidEngine/legui) - Uma API moderna para a criação de interfaces gráficas que está evoluindo rápido, desenvolvida por cima do OpenGL e do LWJGL. Não conheço maiores detalhes para falar a respeito, mas parece promissor.
- [jMonkeyEngine](https://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/jme3/advanced/nifty_gui.html) - Uma API para a criação de jogos 3D em Java, desenvolvida por cima do JOGL e do OpenGL, mas que também permite criar interfaces gráficas 2D. Conheço pouca coisa sobre ela.